# spring boot ldap group and restricted endpoints

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, spring-boot, ldap

I want to restrict certain rest endpoints to be only for LDAP users in a certain group.

I followed the guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ to setup LDAP authentication which is working perfectly. So how do I restrict certain rest endpoints?

I tried

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('developers')")
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public String foo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "Welcome to FOO " + request.getRemoteUser();
}
```

but it still lets users not in the developers group access that endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)` needed to be added to the webSecurityConfig. Once I did that I was able to use `@Secured("ROLE_DEVELOPERS")` and that method was then restricted to that role.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration to something like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .antMatchers("/foo").hasRole("developers")
            .and()
        .formLogin();
}
```

I am not exactly sure of the syntax and if that first rule will override your second rule, but it will be similar to that.

Or, you can try configuring security on a method by method basis like [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-method-security).

Comment: Nope it still allows all users to access /foo

Comment: If you change the ordering it seems to work.
     `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/foo").hasRole("DEVELOPERS").antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();`